# HTML Vertically Center h1

Tags: html, css, inline

I have this html that contains two inline divs:

HTML

```css
div.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>

<div class="inline">
  <h1 class="title"> TOPIC </h1>
</div>
```

The image and the `h1` are shown correctly side by side. Now i would like the `h1` to be vertically centered. It should be somthing like this

```
+----------+
|          |
|   IMG    |    TOPIC 
|          |
+----------+
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Note: `<img>` does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flex

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inline">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>

 <div class="inline">
  <h1 class="title"> TOPIC </h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

for reference: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: That's a lot of stuff considering just adding `vertical-align:middle;` to the parent div will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `vertical-align:middle` as it will align your elements horizontally.

```css
div.inline {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwswZVnaDs2Sn9AyTVbEhdfGc3cCr3tbh_tiytTGd_cJf1d8_a" />
</div>

<div class="inline">
    <h1 class="title"> TOPIC </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to your class (works when `display` is `inline-block`):

```css
div.inline {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/fe2" />
</div>

<div class="inline">
    <h1 class="title"> TOPIC </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the downvote for? I am 100% answering the question - did you look at the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

On your second div apply this style:

```
div.inline{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: webkit browsers have not needed prefixing in years.

Comment: Thanks Rob actually I didn't know about that, I rectified my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

An answer using bootstrap:

Wrap the h1 in a div with d-flex, h-100, justify-content-center, align-items-center

Example:

```
<div class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center>
  <h1>heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the following code.

HTML Code

```
<div class="divBlock">
    <h4 class="hText">H1 Text</h4>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.divBlock {
    display: flex;
}
.hText {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Used inline height property in css

```
inline-height:500px; // height of parents div
```